# C++ Could not convert input string when using cin and variables

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do a simple program where the user inputs a string with his/her name, then if the string is equal to a certain name, it executes different commands.

It's something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

string input = "";

cout << "What's your name?:\n>";
 getline(cin, input);
 if(input = "Micaela"){
    cout << "You're the best" << input << endl << endl;
}
 else
    cout << "You kinda suck" << input << endl << endl;
return 0;
}
```

When compiling, I get the following error:

13 22 C:\Users\Francisco\Desktop\cpp\holanena.cpp [Error] could not convert 'input.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=, std::allocator >(((const char*)"Micaela"))' from 'std::basic_string' to 'bool'

Comment: [Clang gives me a clear warning first](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/854b1ce10ac4c2d5).

Comment: For everyone else: `=` assigns a value. Use `==` to compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs in the line

```
if(input = "Micaela")
```

which assigns `"Micaela"` to `input`. Use comparison operator `==` instead of assignment operator `=` to get what you want:

```
if(input == "Micaela")
```

Answer (score 1):

use `==` instead of `=`
`==` is for comparison
`=` is for assingment

Answer (score 0):

`if(input = "Micaela")`  is an assignment.  You want `if(input == "Micaela")` instead, which is a comparison.